# Layer concatenate was called with an input that isn't a symbolic tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I have two models (model_a,model_b) of similar structure (VGG16 architecture with a replaced top block). I need to concatenate the outputs of the last layers of both models in order to send as input to an attention mechanism.

I run the following line of code for concatenation:

`merged = Concatenate()([model_a.layers[-1].layers[-1], model_b.layers[-1].layers[-1]])`

(`model_a.layers[-1]` is the top block which is a Sequential object, `model_a.layers[-1].layers[-1]` is a Dense layer.)

However, I receive the following error when I try to do so:

> Layer concatenate_8 was called with an input that isn't a symbolic
>   tensor. Received type: < class 'keras.layers.core.Dense' >. Full input:
>   [< keras.layers.core.Dense object at 0x >,
>   < keras.layers.core.Dense object at 0x >]. All inputs to the
>   layer should be tensors.

I noticed that [similar issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44852153/layer-called-with-an-input-that-isnt-a-symbolic-tensor-keras) are fixed by redefining the last layer by specifying the input layer for it, but I'm not sure how that solution would help here since I'm using predefined and pre-trained models.

Comment: Try `model_a.layers[-1].layers[-1].output`. The `output` attribute is the symbolic tensor (the output of that layer)

Comment: @jakub Thank you very much! If you can add the comment as an answer, I can accept it as the correct one :)

Comment: @jakub Actually, when I tried to finally combine inputs and outputs using the Model() method, I had an error - 'Graph disconnected: Cannot get value of tensor Tensor Flatten..' , however when I changed model_a.layers[-1].layers[-1].output to model_a.output and similarly for model_b, the issue was resolved. Any idea why so?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `.output` attribute of the model to access the symbolic tensor.

```
merged = Concatenate()(
    [model_a.layers[-1].layers[-1].output, model_b.layers[-1].layers[-1].output])
```

The [`tensorflow.keras.layers.Layer` documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Layer#attributes_3) states the following about `Layer.output`

> output: Retrieves the output tensor(s) of a layer.
>
> Only applicable if the layer has exactly one output, i.e. if it is connected to one incoming layer.

Regarding the comment

> Actually, when I tried to finally combine inputs and outputs using the `Model()` method, I had an error - `Graph disconnected: Cannot get value of tensor Tensor Flatten..` , however when I changed `model_a.layers[-1].layers[-1].output` to `model_a.output` and similarly for `model_b`, the issue was resolved. Any idea why so?

It's difficult to say without seeing the model code, but you can compare the values of `model_a.layers[-1].layers[-1]` to `model_a.output`.

Comment: model_a.layers[-1].layers[-1] is <tf.Tensor 'dense_2/Sigmoid:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=float32> ; 
model_a.output is <tf.Tensor 'sequential_1/dense_2/Sigmoid:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=float32>